# Probability that a Random Variable is Greater Than Another

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution

Say I have two independent random variables - one is drawn from a uniform distribution on [0,
50] while the other is drawn from a uniform distribution on [0, 100]. How would I calculate the probability that one is greater than the other? TIA

Comment: The probability that $Unif(0,100)>Unif(0,50)$ is exactly 3/4.

Comment: The question should precise what is the dependence relation between both variables. Are they independent?

Comment: @Xi'an sorry, I have now clarified that they are independent

Answer (score 4):

The comment by @user2974951 assumes that the two variables are independent. To understand how [s]he arrived at this result, have a look of the *two dimensional* random variable $(X,Y)$ and integrate over the region where $X>Y$:
[image]

If the two variables are independent with densities $f(x)$ and $g(y)$, respectively, the probability density of $(X,Y)$ is the product of both densities $f(x)\cdot g(y)$.

Comment: An equivalent alternative is to first determine the distribution of $X-Y$.

Comment: You give me too much credit, I just used simulations.